# slice and unslice title on element resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a few div elements on my site who have a  title. It is possible that the title breaks to a new line when resizing the windows.

I would like to avoid that, but the problem I run into is that when I slice the title and input the shorter title into the  tag it works as expected. Now, when I resize the window to the larger element the shorter title is the present. How can I toggle back and forth basically?

This is the code I currently use examines each title's length and if it is larger than 27 characters it will slice it. The code is as follows:

```
new ResizeSensor($('#col1'), function(){
    if($('#col1').width() >= 330) {
        $('.stats').show();

        // how could I check here if the title was sliced and then unslice it?            

    }
    else {
        var titles = [];
        var lengths = [];

        $('.title-header').each(function() {
            var title = $(this).text();
            var length = $(this).text().length;

            titles.push(title);
            lengths.push(length);
        });

        for (var x = 0, len = titles.length; x < len; x++) {
            if (lengths[x] > 27) {
                var newTitle = titles[x].slice(0, -9);
                var oldTitle = $("#col" + x).find(".title-header").text();

                $("#col"+x).find(".title-header").text(newTitle + "...");
            }
        }

        $('.stats').hide();
    }
});
```

I am aware that I can use local storage and store the titles and use those each time the elements are resized. But I am wondering if there is an easier way that I am not thinking or don't know about. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer that I wish my brain had seen much, much earlier:

```
var titles = [];
var lengths = [];

$('.title-header').each(function() {
    var title = $(this).text();
    var length = $(this).text().length;

    console.log('title is '+title);
    titles.push(title);
    lengths.push(length);
});

new ResizeSensor($('#col1'), function(){
    if($('#col1').width() >= 330) {
        for (var x = 0, len = titles.length; x < len; x++) {
            if (lengths[x] <= 33) {
                var newTitle = titles[x];

                $("#col"+x).find(".title-header").text(newTitle);
            }
        }

        $('.stats').show();
    }
    else {
        for (var x = 0, len = titles.length; x < len; x++) {
            if (lengths[x] > 27) {
                var newTitle = titles[x].slice(0, -9);

                $("#col"+x).find(".title-header").text(newTitle + "...");
            }
        }

        $('.stats').hide();
    }
});
```

Just needed to save the arrays before actually resizing so they are available when resizing back and forth.